# Passing Array and String to Custom UIView Class (Subclass) (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, nsmutablearray, subclass

Hope you can help.

I have created my own Custom UIView and I'm trying to pass in a NSMutableArray which I have setup from data from a sqlite DB. I have NSLog'd the Array from the ViewController and everything is showing correctly.

However I want to pass this NSMutableArray into my Custom UIView (it's actually a UIScrollView) so that I can do some magic. However when I do this, my NSLog show's the output as (null).

Here is my code (I've also passed a test string to help to see if it's Array specific, but it isn't):

viewcontroller.m (just shown the Custom class call - NSLog outputs the Array contents (see end  of examples)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
NSString *teststring = @"Testing";
NSLog(@"Subitems: %@", subitems);
SubItemView* subitemview = [[SubItemView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,150,0,0)];
subitemview.cvSubitems = subitems;
subitemview.teststring = teststring;
[self.view addSubview:subitemview];
}
```

customview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SubItemView;

@interface SubItemView : UIScrollView {

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *cvSubitems;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *teststring;

@end
```

customview.m

```
#import "SubItemView.h"

@implementation SubItemView

@synthesize cvSubitems;
@synthesize teststring;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{   
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400);
    NSLog(@"Subclass Properties: %@", self.cvSubitems);
    self = [super initWithFrame:rect];

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

The first NSLog in the viewcontroller.m outputs:

```
Subitems: (
    "<SubItems: 0x6894400>",
    "<SubItems: 0x6894560>"
)
```

The second NSLog from the Custom UIScrollView outputs:

```
Subclass Properties: (null)
```

I am a bit of a newbie, so I'm obviously missing something (possibly obvious) here. I am just really struggling to pass an Array and even a simple string into a Custom class and just output it's contents via NSLog.

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well when your initWithFrame method is called, your cvSubitems property isn't set yet, as it is set only **after** your call to initWithFrame.

Try again to log your arrays value in a method that is called after your view is initialized, or provide a custom init method (e.g. `initWithMyData: andFrame:`) to solve this issue.

Comment: viewWillAppear is a UIViewController method, not a UIView method.

Comment: Many thanks. In the end I overrode the initWithFrame init method and added the array to be passed in there.

.h
`-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame teststring:(NSString *)ts cvsubitems:(NSMutableArray *)cvs;`

.m
`-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame teststring:(NSString *)ts cvsubitems:(NSMutableArray *)cvs {
    self.teststring = ts;
    self.cvSubitems = cvs;
    ...`

Comment: @PaulPounder although this may have worked it seems like you have fixed the symptom and not the problem. You should make sure you understand the answers that are given here. The `init` method you have in your last comment is also not of the proper recommended form and could potentially lead to some very subtle hard to trace bugs

Answer (score 1):

So to clarify what has already been said, you are calling out of order.

```
1| SubItemView* subitemview = [[SubItemView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,150,0,0)];
2| subitemview.cvSubitems = subitems;
3| subitemview.teststring = teststring;
```

- On line 1 you are calling the `initWithFrame:` method on `SubItemView`
- On lines 2 and 3 you are setting the ivars

The point being that you are setting the ivars (lines 2+3) after the `initWithFrame:` method has returned.

**But** you are trying to print the ivars in the `initWithFrame:` method

You are also trying to log the ivars before you have even assigned `self` which is not a good idea either

```
NSLog(@"Subclass Properties: %@", self.cvSubitems);
self = [super initWithFrame:rect];
```

To prove that they are being set you can just print from where you instantiate:

```
SubItemView *subitemview = [[SubItemView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,150,0,0)];
subitemview.cvSubitems = subitems;
subitemview.teststring = teststring;
NSLog(@"Subclass Properties: %@", subitemview.cvSubitems);
```